# PHP Joomla 2.5 MySQL Load Data Infile - Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I'm trying to load a CSV file into a table. I'm getting a permission denied error:

```
Error importing CSV File: (1045) Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES) 
SQL=LOAD DATA INFILE '//homeX/username/public_html/activator/uploadedCSV/20180603064917_csvtoimport.csv'
  IGNORE INTO TABLE `csv_import_temp` 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  ESCAPED BY '\\' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
  IGNORE 1 ROWS 
  ( contact_lname, contact_email ) ;
```

The csv file exists, and has permissions set to `0644`.

The SQL statement is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '//homeX/username/public_html/activator/uploadedCSV/20180603064917_csvtoimport.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE `csv_import_temp`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(
    contact_lname,
    contact_email
);
```

I've tried using it with both a leading single slash and the double slash (as above) in the filename. I've also tried running it in phpAdmin and get the same error message.

The site is hosted on a Hostgator shared account.

I've added code to verify that the file exists, and has the right permissions, and it says it does. But MySQL doesn't seem to be able to access the file.

Yes, I know that Joomla 2.5 is end of life, but for many reasons, this site can't be upgraded, and is only used for admin functions.

Any suggestions would be welcome as the alternative is to read the file with PHP  and insert each row which would be much slower.

The first 4 lines of the CSV:

```
"name","email"
"John Smith","xxx1@yyy.edu"
"John Doe","xxx2@yyy.edu"
"Jane Doe","xxx3@yyy.edu"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually due to you not including the LOCAL keyword. Try:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//homeX/username/public_html/activator/uploadedCSV/20180603064917_csvtoimport.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE `csv_import_temp`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY ''
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(
    contact_email,
    contact_email
);
```

The permission error is misleading, it relates to trying to the mysql system directories rather than the file you are trying to read.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! Now it's running, but only imports the 1st entry of 293 lines in the file. Could that be because of the IGNORE on the 2nd line of the query?

Comment: Glad it helped to get you started! `IGNORE` is used to exclude headings, etc. so it should be starting with the second line. Is the data non-confidential? If so, you could post another question and include lines 1-4 and hopefully we can sort that problem out too.

Comment: I added the first 4 lines. Data changed as it contains real names and email addresses.

Comment: Try removing `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`, that looks wrong.

Comment: Nope, still only 1 row imported. The lines in the file are terminated with \r\n characters rather than \n.

Comment: What's the significance of importing `contact_email` twice? Should they not be different? Is it possible there's a field/column not included in the import that needs to be unique and non-null? Trying INSERTing the second line manually, you should get more feedback.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: Found the issue. The id column is supposed to be auto-increment, but that wasn't set. Once that was fixed, it imports the whole file. Thanks again for your help!!